# How to get Key / Id of the data written into Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a application which stores employee records, it stores the employees ID, but also needs each employee to have a local ID, I want to use the ID generated by Firebase when we push data onto the db using `push()` function as the internal ID for each employee. This is required for change management.

My code:

```
function submit()
    {


    var dsRef=new Firebase("https://dataretrievaltest-28983.firebaseio.com/EmployeeDB/EInfo");

    var name=document.getElementById('Name').value;
    var eid=document.getElementById('EID').value;
    var email=document.getElementById('Email').value;

    dsRef
                    .push(
                            {
                            Name:name,
                            EID: eid,
                            Email: email,
                            }
                        );

    var pushid=dsRef.name;
    console.log("name:"+pushid);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(eid);
    console.log(email);

    }
```

Output of the above code:

```
name:function (){S("Firebase.name() being deprecated. Please use Firebase.key() instead.");D("Firebase.name",0,0,arguments.length);return this.key()}
savekey.html:104 Djoko
savekey.html:105 0143
savekey.html:106 Djoko@dept.com
```

Have used Key in place of name as name is deprecated but did not get the key, instead it returns a function.

The code with key in place of name

```
var pushid=dsRef.key;
console.log("name:"+pushid);
```

Output after change:

```
name:function (){D("Firebase.key",0,0,arguments.length);return this.path.e()?null:me(this.path)}
savekey.html:104 Caroline
savekey.html:105 0192
savekey.html:106 caroline@dept.com
```

I need the Keys viz -Kb5... : which is seen in below Json

```
"EInfo" : {
      "-Kb5UunYfq-8zd_Jc2Nd" : {
        "EID" : "0134",
        "Email" : "Parker@dept.com",
        "Name" : "Parker"
      },
      "-Kb5V9xHhzVix6BNRM78" : {
        "EID" : "1024",
        "Email" : "sanchez@dept.com",
        "Name" : "sanchez"
      }
}
```

The available properties(key/name) don't give the required output. Please let me know how to retrieve the key and if I am missing anything.

Also tried

```
var pushid=dsRef.child("EInfo").push().key;
console.log("name:"+pushid);
```

it did not give the desired result.

```
name:function (){D("Firebase.key",0,0,arguments.length);return this.path.e()?null:me(this.path)}
savekey.html:104 camila
savekey.html:105 0172
savekey.html:106 camila@dept.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Firebase SDK version 2.x, but are mixing in syntax from version 3.x. For Firebase 2.x, the syntax to get the key is:

```
var pushid=dsRef.key();
console.log("name:"+pushid);
```

If you're creating this app now, you should really be using Firebase 3.x SDKs, in which case the syntax would indeed be `dsRef.key` (without parentheses).

#### Update

You seem to be looking for the key of the item that you just created with `push()`. You can get that by assigning the result from `push` to a variable:

```
var newRef = dsRef.push({
    Name:name,
    EID: eid,
    Email: email,
});
console.log(newRef.key()); // or newRef.key when using SDK version 3.x
```

Comment: I want the unique key generated by firebase not the url key,please refer the Json

Comment: Thank You @Frank van Puffelen